# Tratar erro ao conectar ao MySQL com PDO

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, exceção, try-catch

Pessoal gostaria de tratar o erro que ocorre caso o servidor MySQL não esteja rodando, quero que apareça somente uma mensagem então fiz o seguinte código:

```
function mensagemErro () {
  throw new \Exception("Error connecting to database");
}

function connect() {
  try {
    $pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB;charset=utf8", 'root', 'root');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    return $pdo;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      mensagemErro();
      echo $e->getMessage();
  }

}
```

Porém não está aparecendo a mensagem personalizada, somente o Fatal Error: < caminho do arquivo.php > on line 11
E não quero que aparece o nome do arquivo e a linha do erro, somente a mensagem.

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro completa? Um `Fatal Error` não é uma exceção.

Comment: Tem uma função nativa do `PHP` que pode atender de maneira simples a sua necessidade , ela se chama `PDO::errorInfo` que tem uma função similar a `mysqli_error`.   Link:http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Sim, o Fatal Error não é pego pelo catch porque não é uma exceção.
Vou testar com o PDO::errorInfo, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri que não é possível pegar Fatal Errors com catch pois esse tipo de erro faz o programa parar.

Então reformulei a função que conecta ao MySQL começando por desabilitar esse tipo de erro com ini_set('display_errors', 0); e utilizando o tratamento de erro do PDO PDOException:

```
function connect() {
  try {
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    $pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=BassamBrasil;charset=utf8", 'root', 'root');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    return $pdo;
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    //cho 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    echo 'ERROR: Error connecting to database';
  }

}
```

Bom, acredito que essa seja a melhor maneira de mostrar somente a mensagem personalizada.